# Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication Load Balancing in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication, load-balancing

I'm looking at [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196(v=sql.110).aspx) and it looks like a perfect fit for my requirements, but there's one unclear part - load balancing (see picture below).
[image: Load Balancing]

**How it is implemented in SQL Server? Is it programmable? Or it's something that I should implement myself? If so, what's the best way of doing that?**

My business rules are:

- **Server A** and **Server B** are in different geographical locations.
- Data is replicated between both servers constantly.
- If **Server A** becomes unavailable, its users requests are redirected to **Server B**. Some data loss is acceptable in this case.
- If user performed some writes on **Server A** - he must keep using **Server A** (with only one exception, when **Server A** becomes unavailable). The user can't perform some writes on **Server A** and some writes on **Server B**. But he may perform reads from both servers.

Both servers uses MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise.

*AlwaysOn Availability Groups* and *SQL Server Cluster* for some reasons is not an option for me.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a "turn load balancing on" switch - you'll need to do this externally (the last time I did this we used [F5 gear](https://f5.com/products) - but I'm sure you can do this with other products as well).

Comment: In production we'll use F5, but now we need some simpler solution. Something like Application Request Routing (ARR) in IIS, but for databases. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [F5 BIG-IP LTM Virtual Edition](https://www.f5.com/trial/big-ip-ltm-virtual-edition.php), because I didn't find any other free solutions, that fits my business requirements.